# Can someone write this code with better logic?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dft

I am stuck with this problem for 2 days. Can someone help me with the logic ?

I am working on C++ programs for good algorithms. I am now working on the Danielson-Lanczos Algorithm to compute the FFT of a sequence.

Looking at

```
mmax=2;
while (n>mmax) {
    istep = mmax<<1;
    theta = -(2*M_PI/mmax);
    wtemp = sin(0.5*theta);
    wpr = -2.0*wtemp*wtemp;
    wpi = sin(theta);
    wr = 1.0;
    wi = 0.0;

    for (m=1; m < mmax; m += 2) {
        for (i=m; i <= n; i += istep) {
            j=i+mmax;
            tempr = wr*data[j-1] - wi*data[j];
            tempi = wr * data[j] + wi*data[j-1];

            data[j-1] = data[i-1] - tempr;
            data[j] = data[i] - tempi;
            data[i-1] += tempr;
            data[i] += tempi;
        }
        wtemp=wr;
        wr += wr*wpr - wi*wpi;
        wi += wi*wpr + wtemp*wpi;
    }
    mmax=istep;
}
```

Source: http://www.eetimes.com/design/signal-processing-dsp/4017495/A-Simple-and-Efficient-FFT-Implementation-in-C--Part-I

Is there any way to logically write a code such that the whole `for-loop` portion is reduced to just 4 lines of code  (or even better)?

Comment: Just remove the newlines in the loop body ;-)

Comment: *Why* do you want to reduce the *line count*? Fewer lines does not necessarily mean better code, in any sense... In what respect do you want to make your code better?

Comment: @thkala: and use the comma operator!

Comment: Don't use "temp" in variable names, either.

Comment: @thkala: I agree :) but yes generally, i am just very curios how 15 lines of code can be put in three lines. The logic should be awesome !!!

Comment: This code is not from the source you quote. It is originally from the Numerical Recipes series of textbooks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better indentation would go a long way. I fixed that for you. Also, this seems to beg for better locality of the variables. The variable names are not clear to me, but that might be because I don't know the domain this algorithm belongs to.

Generally, if you want to make complex code easier to understand, identify sub-algorithms and put them into their own (inlined) functions. (Putting a code snippet into a function effectively gives it a name, and makes the passing of variables into and out of the code more obvious. Often, that makes code easier to digest.)
I'm not sure this is necessary for this piece of code, though.

Merely *condensing* code, however, will not make it more readable. Instead, it will just make it more condensed.

Answer (score 5):

Do *not* compress your code. Please? Pretty please? With a cherry on top?

Unless you can create a better *algorithm*, compressing an existing piece of code will only make it look like something straight out of the gates of Hell itself. No one would be able to understand it. *You* would not be able to understand it, even a few days later.

Even the compiler might get too confused by all the branches to properly optimize it.

If you are trying to improve performance, consider the following:

1. Premature optimization is the source of all evils.
2. Work on your algorithms first, then on your code.
3. The line count may have absolutely no relation to the size of the produced executable code.
4. Compilers do not like entangled code paths and complex expressions. Really...
5. Unless the code is *really* performance critical, readability trumps *everything* else.
6. If it *is* performance critical, profile first, then start optimizing.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a complex number class to reflect the math involved.

A good part of the code is made of two complex multiplications.

You can rewrite your code as :

```
unsigned long mmax=2;
while (n>mmax)
{
    unsigned long istep = mmax<<1;
    const complex wp = coef( mmax );
    complex w( 1. , 0. );
    for (unsigned long m=1; m < mmax; m += 2)
    {
        for (unsigned long i=m; i <= n; i += istep)
        {
            j=i+mmax;
            complex temp = w * complex( data[j-1] , data[j] );
            complexref( data[j-1] , data[j] ) = complex( data[i-1] , data[i] ) - temp ;
            complexref( data[i-1] , data[i] ) += temp ;
        }
        w += w * wp ;
    }
    mmax=istep;
}
```

With :

```
struct complex
{
    double r , i ;
    complex( double r , double i ) : r( r ) , i( i ) {}

    inline complex & operator+=( complex const& ref )
    {
        r += ref.r ;
        i += ref.i ;
        return *this ;
    }
};

struct complexref
{
    double & r , & i ;
    complexref( double & r , double & i ) : r( r ) , i( i ) {}

    inline complexref & operator=( complex const& ref )
    {
        r = ref.r ;
        i = ref.i ;
        return *this ;
    }

    inline complexref & operator+=( complex const& ref )
    {
        r += ref.r ;
        i += ref.i ;
        return *this ;
    }
}    ;

inline complex operator*( complex const& w , complex const& b )
{
    return complex(
        w.r * b.r - w.i * b.i ,
        w.r * b.i + w.i * b.r
    );
}

inline complex operator-( complex const& w , complex const& b )
{
    return complex( w.r - b.r , w.i - b.i );
}
inline complex coef( unsigned long mmax )
{
    double theta = -(2*M_PI/mmax);
    double wtemp = sin(0.5*theta);
    return complex( -2.0*wtemp*wtemp , sin(theta) );
}
```

Comment: "Make it shorter by adding a lot of code which can be used as a one-off here?"

Comment: The intend is to make the complex numbers appear as such, not to be shorter as a whole. The fft code part is shorter, and the complex code should be provided from some external library.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't believe you would be able to make it substantially shorter.
2. If this code were made much shorter, I would guess that it would significantly diminish readability.
3. Since the logic is relatively clear, number of lines does not matter — unless you're planning on using this on codegolf.stackexchange.com, this is a place where you should trust your compiler to help you (because it will)
4. This strikes me as premature optimization.